# Save response to text file

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to create 2 files. First, response to .png (which worked). Second, take all html and save to text. Saving html to text file is only showing blank.

```
def parse_request(self, response):

    # Works and saves file and png
    with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)

    # Creates file but doesnt have any text in it
    with open('text.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try storing `response.body` to a variable then `write` that variable?

I think your exhausting the stream response during the first read.  I'm also guessing your probably storing the entire response not just the png in the  `image.png` file.

```
def parse_request(self, response):
    body = response.body
    # Works and saves file and png
    with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(body)

    # Creates file but doesnt have any text in it
    with open('text.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(body.decode("utf-8"))
```